# Why does the Get-ADUser -Filter command not accept $_ as input?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, get-aduser

I have been troubleshooting code today and I discovered that this code does not work. I am using a PowerShell pipeline to send an array of distinguished names to search Active Directory for users with a manager.

```
$managers | Get-ADUser -Filter {manager -eq $_}
```

However, if I expand the command to this example with a `foreach-object` loop and an explicit variable, the code does work.

```
$managers | %{$manager = $_; Get-ADUser -Filter {manager -eq $manager}}
```

What part of the source code forces users to write out expressions like this?

I'm not familiar with the source code for `Get-ADUser`, but in working with native PSCustomObjects, using the pipeline works as expected in the first example.

Comment: What do you expect to be in $_? Now think about why that isn't the case.
Try this: `$managers | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter {manager -eq $_}}`

Comment: -filter Accept pipeline input: False, granted it's unusual

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is [`-Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-filter) does not take pipeline input hence no [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) is possible. And there is a good reason for this, the filter used needs to be passed as is to the [Filter Provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)), **cannot be evaluated beforehand**.

As a minimal example, try this function which's `-Filter` parameter takes [`ValueFromPipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefrompipeline-argument) and then remove the `ValueFromPipeline`.

```
function Get-ADThing {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $Filter
    )

    process {
        $Filter
    }
}

'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | Get-ADThing -Filter { "name -eq $_" }
```